# php access sub elemement in XML

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I am using simplexml in PHP to parse an XML document. I have the following element I am not able to create the proper path to one of the sub elements. Here is the element:

```
<wp:category>
<wp:term_id>13</wp:term_id>
<wp:category_nicename>cleaner</wp:category_nicename>
<wp:category_parent></wp:category_parent>
<wp:cat_name><![CDATA[CLEANER]]></wp:cat_name>
```

The element I need to access is `<wp:cat_name>`.

What path would I use to access the data?

lee

---

$wp->category->cat_name; is the path to the element.

Comment: The easiest way is to using SimpleXMLElement

Comment: I'm guessing you are using SimpleXML, which does not play nice with CDATA - the key word is "simple" ;-) - you should use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) for this. Also, please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried $wp->category->cat_name; I was certain this would not work, but I really had no other ideas.

Comment: Ok. I tried the same call again, and now it seems to be working fine. Now idea why. (perhaps it was my unwarranted skepticism) - Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just import your xml as a `DomDocument` without preserving namespaces

```
$xml ='
<wp:category>
    <wp:term_id>13</wp:term_id>
    <wp:category_nicename>cleaner</wp:category_nicename>
    <wp:category_parent></wp:category_parent>
    <wp:cat_name ><![CDATA[CLEANER]]></wp:cat_name>
</wp:category>';

$data = new DOMDocument;
$data->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$data->loadXml($xml, LIBXML_NOERROR);
foreach($data->documentElement->childNodes as $child)
{
    if($child->nodeName == 'cat_name')
    {
        print_r($child->nodeValue);
    }
}
```

this will output

```
CLEANER
```